# Work Flow Foundation Best Performnace Tips?

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, sharepoint-workflow

I am starting to write a Best performance white paper for my organization for using Microsoft Work Flow Foundation.

Can any one point me to any link for the same or provide there inputs on what are the best performnace techniques and tips for working with MS WFF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [WF4 Performance Tip–Cache Activities](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/02/12/wf4-performance-tip-cache-activities.aspx)
and [Windows Workflow Foundation 4 Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg281645.aspx)